# How to attach an image directly (automatically) to an email on Android?

Tags: android, image, email

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to attach an image directly to a send email portal instead of opening up the gallery for users to select?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: check my answer and reply

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"image.png");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  Uri.parse("file:///"+file));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Picture Via Email"));
```

Comment: do I have to import any libraries to use the 'File'?

Comment: I was able to import the library java.io in order to use the File. I was able to compile your codes in my application, however it will still prompts me to attach file with pop out dialog box. May I know how am I able to attach an image after photo taking automatically whenever I click on 'Attach' button without the need to navigate in photo collection?